# HTML5 Input range slider step like 5 10 25 50 100 1000

Tags: html, reactjs, input, slider, range

Is possible to make step value as dynamic with native HTML5 input[type="range"].

Can marks the slider values on slide to the following values like

min = 130 and max = 240

But the slider should only slide to the values from the array

[130, 133, 135, 137, 140, 143, 145, 147, 150, ....,230, 235, 237, 240]

In this library, they doing what I expecting with html5 input type range with custom div's
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider

Need to make slider should slide only at hash marked values from array

Answer (score 0):

have you tried input **type=range** and **datalist**

```
<input type="range" min="130" max="240" list="customrange" />
<datalist id="customrange">
  <option value="130"></option> 
  <option value="133"></option> 
  <option value="135"></option> 
  <option value="137"></option>
  <option value="140"></option> 
  .
  .
  .
  <option value="240"></option> 
</datalist>
```

Although I'm not sure if all browsers support it.

P.S. just to be clear, those option data could be dynamic. Depends on how you want to design it. Could be from server-side or client-side. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bro. Still, I didn't achieve the same functionality as the RC slider.